# dynamic binding in ListBox using Task Class in c#,WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, facebook, listbox, task

I'm developing related FaceBook Application using WPF,C#.

and I developed to receive photo through Facebook API(graph.facebook/{album id}/photos).

But I want to receive async and update ListBox in WPF.

**So I totally want to know how I can update ListBox in WPF using Task Class.**

please, help me.

Comment: learn Func<T> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx

Comment: You should post some code...

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started ...

```
var dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
var loadTask = new Task( () =>
    {
        Image image = YourMethodThatLoadsImagesFromFB();
        if ( dispatcher.CheckAccess() )
        {
            YourMethodWhichProcessesReceivedImages( image );
        }
        else
        {
            dispatcher.BeginInvoke( YourMethodWhichProcessesReceivedImages, image);
        }
    } );
loadTask.Start();
```

Comment: thanks for answer. But I can't apply to my application using your comment. if you are Ok. please can you make simple example? just add image to itembox using your comment. I'm trying to apply to my application. thank you

Comment: Busy now but will try to get to this over the wkend. Can you post a snippet of your code which loads from the FB API?